# How do I get the Dell 3007wfphc monitor to do other resolutions?

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution

I've borrowed a [Dell 3007 WFP-HC monitor](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/monitors/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=222-7175) and it will only do 1280x800 and 2560x1600 resolutions crisply due to its lack of a real scaler.  Every other resolution is fuzzy.  1280x800 is pixelated and I doubt my PC can play games at a reasonable frame rate at 2560x1600.  Can I get something in between that looks good?

I have a GeForce GTX 560 video card and Windows 7.  Is it possible to get the GPU to render at a more reasonable resolution, say 1920x1200, and stretch it to the native 2560x1600 to make the monitor happy?  I've been poking at the NVIDIA Control Panel but to no effect.

*UPDATE*: The NVIDIA control panel marks 1280x800 as "native" and not 2560x1600.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*(**Note:** I only have my work machine running an Nvidia card, and that is on WinXP, so some of the directions may require adaptation to the Windows 7 version of the utility).*

First you need to enable the resolution, and since your display doesn't have 1920x1200, you have to create a custom resolution.  In Nvidia Control Panel, go to the `Change Resolution` page, and select `Custom Resolution`.  It should show you a list of a whole bunch of resolutions, but you want to select `1920x1200 at 60Hz (32-bit)`.  If this is greyed-out, make sure to check the box that says `Enable resolutions not exposed by the display`.  If this resolution is *not* available in the list, you will have to create your own custom resolution, setting Horiz pixels to `1920`, Vert lines to `1200`, and refresh rate to `60`.

Now, if your monitor truly doesn't have a scaler, then the picture will be resized and smaller than the actual area of the display. To correct this, go to `Adjust desktop size and position` tab and select `Use NVIDIA scaling`. You could also choose `Use NVIDIA scaling with fixed-aspect ratio`; it doesn't matter since both 1200p and your monitor's native resolution are both 8:5.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'd poked at the custom resolution thing and it gave me **DIRE WARNINGS** that they could not be held responsible for what happened next. Not wanting to open a 30" portal to Hell (even the smaller demons that can squeeze through can be trouble) I demurred. Also its a borrowed monitor so I don't feel as cavalier as if it were my own. ANYWAY if it worked for you I'll give it a shot. But first... **AVAUNT!!!** Ok, you're not a demon here to trick me.